# Toastr notification on sign in not working

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, toastr

The point is for the user to log in with their google account, and then for a toast to pop up saying, "Hey there, NAME!". However, the toast doesn't appear; I've checked the console, and it's empty! Here's the code I'm referencing:

```
$().ready(function(){

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }

    toastr.info('Hey there, '+profile.getName());

});
```

Goal:
[image]
Here's the code: https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/moEmqr?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to toastr sits outside the onSignIn function, so when you call *profile.getName()* profile doesn't exist.

Move the toastr call up a few lines  between the

```
console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
```

and closing brace.

Comment: Yeah, I got it; Thanks though.